# How to make Facebook like button narrower than 225px?

Tags: facebook

I'm generating a like button with Facebook's 'standard' layout for my site via https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ . I've set its width to 200 pixels, but notice that setting it to lower than 225 pixels has no effect, and the documentation on that page indeed specifies 225px as the minimum width for the standard layout. Unfortunately I need to make it 200 pixels wide to fit my site's design. Is there any way to force it into this width?

(The site's at http://gwwc2.centreforeffectivealtruism.org/ if you want to have a play with Firebug, though the like button gets generated by javascript so you'd probably have to duplicate that page and edit its source.)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the width restriction is the text displayed to non logged in users.

You'll find that if you shrink lower than 225px for ***that*** button style some users will find your layout disrupted (I've tried exactly this, the results were not good).

You can, however, choose a different button style.

- Uncheck the send button option
- Choose the button_count option
- Set the width to 200px
- Uncheck show faces

And you'll get this:-

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="200" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial"></div>
```

Which fits your width requirement. Using box_count will also work well.

Comment: Thanks, but my question was how to do this with Facebook's 'standard' layout - I want the faces.

Comment: @tog22 basically you can't, there is a good reason for the minimum width + facebook regularly update the widget, which will break your code.

Answer (score 0):

Take out `&width=225` in the iFrame `src` attribute and pass no width at all. In the iframe `style` attribute, specify a css value `width:200px;` If you pass a value smaller than the minimum in the source URL, facebook will ignore it, but if you custom style the iframe itself to be that width, the contents will squeeze inside.

Comment: To clarify, the code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ that I've used is `<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/givingwhatwecan" data-send="false" data-width="200" data-show-faces="true"></div>`. This plus the JS from that page generates the iframe, so I can't edit it's `src` directly. Are you instead suggesting I add the generated code directly to my page, and edited the `src` within it?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure, maybe they've changed the generated code since the last time I used it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a CSS rule that states `iframe { width:200px !important; )`

I would make that rule specific to whatever DIV or container your Facebook widget is inside of. And of course, if it looks bad after you do this, you can take it out. But if you're just including a "Like" button (no faces), it should work.